# data encountered at first instance of date is returned in sequelize

Tags: date, sequelize.js

I wrote a query to get the data from the table where the data of today's date is to be fetched, if data for today's date isn't present, then the latest data from latest date in the past is fetched.

```
var db_data = await db.daily_tip({
       where: { date_for_show: { [Op.lte]: payload_date }
 })
```

where, if data encountered at the first instance which is less than the current date is fetched.

How do I modify this query to return the data as of this query

```
SELECT id,tip,date_for_show from daily_tip WHERE date_for_show <= '${payload_date}' ORDER BY date_for_show DESC LIMIT 1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `order` and `limit` options like this:

```js
var db_data = await db.daily_tip({
       where: { date_for_show: { [Op.lte]: payload_date },
       order: [['date_for_show', 'DESC']],
       limit: 1
 })
```